# 64 bit Xen install, Network Issue

Tags: xen

I'm playing around with a test server, install Xen on a Centos 5 box.

http://www.howtoforge.org/paravirtua...tos-5.3-x86_64

I've tried two methods to create a vm.

virt-install

and

virt-install -x "ip=xxx.xxx.70.212 gateway=xxx.xxx.70.211 subnet=255.255.255.248"

If I do virt-install, it asks me this:

http://i40.tinypic.com/2m5c8ys.png

Automatic DHCP never works.  If I try manual config, I have no idea what to put it. I did try this:

IPv4 address: xxx.xxx.70.212__ / 255.255.255.248_ 
Gateway: xxx.xxx.70.211___________________________
Name Server: _________________________________________

note: only here in my post am I actually putting "xxx" in the IP for
privacy reasons only. The 70.212 is the main server IP that I ssh into.

See 2nd screenshot for error. Same thing with various valid mirrors I tried.

http://i40.tinypic.com/64fqyh.png

This is my ifcfg-eth0 info:

DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.70.212
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet

I've tried 2 different mirrors so far, same error.

http://wftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/5.3/os/x86_64
http://mirror.its.uidaho.edu/pub/centos/5/os/x86_64/

My resolvers are just fine too in /etc/resolv.conf

Note, I did not do anything at all. I had a fresh Centos 5 64bit install and then followed that Xen install guideline. That's it.

Comment: You might consider accepting some answers on your previous questions prior to expecting results on this one :)

Comment: Its a Dell 850 actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been building 64-bit Xen hosts on Dell 2850 and 2950s without problem... Looking at your virt-install option though I believe you want `netmask=x.x.x.x` rather than `subnet=x.x.x.x` as that's the only difference I see directly off hand.

If that is the only options to the command line you're using for virt-install you need to include a NIC using the `-w` option to add it to one or more of your Xen bridges. My typical call for virt-install is:

```
virt-install -n <hostname> -r <memory> -p --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel5 \
-f /dev/xenvg/<hostname> -l http://KS-REPO/redhat/linux/enterprise/5/en/os/i386 \
--vcpus=1 -w bridge:xenbr0 --nographics --noautoconsole \
-x "ks=http://KS-REPO/ks/KICKSTART.KS ip=x.x.x.x netmask=255.255.255.x \
gateway=x.x.x.x dns=PRI-DNS-IP,SEC-DNS-IP"
```

In most cases I tend to have a 64-bit host but 32-bit guests... could modify to work with 64-bit guests if I needed to. This gives me 2 NICs (eth0 and eth1) attached to the xenbr0 and xenbr1 bridges respectively, single CPU guest installing a RHEL5 variant.

Comment: Not working, please help.

Tried your method (note, the link you posted is not a valid domain anyway)


Yours: 
http://tinypaste.com/62d674b

Mine, Modified:

http://tinypaste.com/b3f36

Comment: Okay... Can you provide the output of '/sbin/ip addr show'? It looks like your bridge names and mine don't match. The domain wasn't meant to be real as the Kickstart Repo (KS-REPO) I use is an internal mirror host you wouldn't have been able to reach.

Comment: Check out http://tinypaste.com/f3981 for an example I ran running a CentOS 5 x86_64 guest... Do check out the bridge names on your system as those might be different and I use LVM slices for physical drives for the VM rather than image files.

Comment: Thanks. This is the output. 

http://tinypaste.com/e915440

Comment: Looks like you only have the one bridged NIC as xenbr0 while I have both xenbr0 and xenbr1... You can confirm with the 'brctl show' command I showed in my paste URL.

Comment: Ok thanks, output is:

http://tinypaste.com/3d026

Comment: Then you should be able to use: virt-install -n vm01 -r 256 -p --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel5 -f /vm/vm01.img -l http://wftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/5.3/os/x86_64 --vcpus=1 -w bridge:xenbr0 --nographics --noautoconsole -x "ks=http://wftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/5.3/os/x86_64 ip=xxx.xxx.64.170 netmask=255.255.255.248 gateway=xxx.xxx.64.169 dns=PRI-DNS-IP,SEC-DNS-IP" provided you update the DNS IP addresses and the other IP information.

Comment: Great! That works, (results: http://tinypaste.com/a6ba0) but now a new problem. I entered the vm01 console via this command: "xm console vm01 " and all I see is this screen. http://tinypic.com/r/k16fjq/5

Comment: Another error: http://tinypaste.com/e5a219f

Comment: Looks like screen refresh issue... Try removing the "--noautoconsole" and it should go straight into console mode for you... If you hit `tab` it should move through the dialog screen as normal and force refresh. I typically use a kickstart script to do automated installations so use the "--noautoconsole" to let it run in background

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a Dell 2950 (or any other Dell x9xx using a Broadcom NetXtreme II) I suggest that you follow http://lists.xensource.com/archives/html/xen-users/2007-04/msg00629.html